# Are there any great replacement lenses for the Nexus 5?

Tags: lens, smartphone

I really like my Nexus 5 (Android Phone), and I use it to take a lot of pictures. Recently, it seems that there are couple of dust spots on the sensor, which leads to some black dots in live view and in the pictures. This is pretty annoying. I am thinking about replacing the original lens with a better one; does anyone know which lens could be compatible with Nexus 5, preferably a large aperture one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really do this. Smartphones are designed as a whole, and the camera isn't *meant* to have its lens replaced. In this case, the camera lens is part of the rear housing:

[image: it's all a thing]

and as you can see, it's not really designed for multiple options. You *might* be able to hack something up, but the market for such a thing is so tiny that I'm sure it'd be a one-off DIY exercise, not a product you could find somewhere. (You *can* buy drop-in replacements for just the cracked rear lens, but they're meant to replicate the original, not provide alternatives.)

If you just want to do a simple swap, this part is called the "[midframe](https://www.ifixit.com/Store/Parts/Nexus-5-Midframe/IF293-003-1)" on iFixit, by the way, and it goes for $7, although it's currently (and possibly permanently) out of stock — look on eBay instead.

It's possible, though, that you could solve your problem just by taking this panel out and carefully — use a brush designed for the purpose, plus rocket-style blower rather than compressed air! — cleaning it. You should be able to figure out if the dust is *inside* this lens, or under it, or on the front of the camera module, or *inside* the camera. The iFixit site has a [step-by-step guide for replacing the camera module](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Nexus+5+Rear+Facing+Camera+Replacement/32344), which you could use if it comes to the worst case, or, of course, use *partway* to get to what you need to clean in better cases.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any smartphones which have a replaceable lens (and certainly not a replaceable *sensor*), so I think you're out of luck here. What you're perhaps being confused by are the accessory lenses which can be clipped onto the outside of a phone to give (normally) telephoto capabilities, but they still use the original sensor and lens.